# Real time activity feed - code / platform implementation?

Tags: php, database, stream

I am defining out specs for a live activity feed on my website. I have the backend of the  data model done but the open area is the actual code development where my development team is lost on the best way to make the feeds work. Is this purely done by writing custom code or do we need to use existing frameworks to make the feeds work in real time? Some suggestions thrown to me were to use reverse AJAX for this. Some one mentioned having the client poll the server every x seconds but i dont like this because it is unwanted server traffic if there are no updates. I was also mentioned a push engine like light streamer to push from server to browser.

So in the end: What is the way to go? Is it code related, purely pushing SQL quires, using frameworks, using platforms, etc.

My platform is written in PHP codeignitor and DB is MySQL.

The activity stream will have lots of activities. There are 42 components on the social networking I am developing, each component has approx 30ish unique activities that can be streamed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.stream-hub.com/

Comment: Are there open source packages?

Comment: im pretty sure it is. http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet-streamhub/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

I have been using superfeedr.com with Rails and I can tell you it works really well. Here are a few facts about it:

**Pros**

- Julien, the lead developer is very helpful when you encounter a problem.
- Immediate push of new feed entries which support PubSubHubHub.
- JSon response which is perfect for parsing whoever you'd like.
- Retrieve API in case the update callback fails and you need to retrieve the latest entries for a given feed.

**Cons**

- Documentation is not up to the standards I would like, so you'll likely end up searching the web to find obscure implementation details.
- You can't control how often superfeedr fetches each feed, they user a secret algorithm to determine that.
- The web interface allows you to manage your feeds but becomes difficult to use when you subscribe to a loot of them
- Subscription verification mechanism works synchronous so you need to make sure the object URL is ready for the superfeedr callback to hit it (they do provide an async option which does not seem to work well).

Overall I would recommend superfeedr as a good solution for what you need.